# Django Test_Deferred

Tags: django

I am trying to perform a simple RAW query by following [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly][1]

My model is:

```
   class Test(models.Model):
      ID = models.IntegerField()
```

My RAW query is:

```
   for p in Test.objects.raw('select ID from table')
      print(p)
```

Yet, when I run the code I'm given 'Test_Deferred_ID' in the terminal. What does '**Deferred**' mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a raw query like you are doing in your example, where you are selecting a specific field in the database, you will get back a **deffered model instance**. What this means in effect is that the other fields of your model (the ones that you are not `SELECT`ing) will not be loaded until you actually try to retrieve them. So if you do `print(p.some_field)`, `some_field` will be loaded at that time but not earlier. That is what the `Deffered` in your instance is referring to.

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields) in the documentation for more information.